# How to change appearance of jQueryUI slider bar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I need a drag slider bar for my webpage. This is how the jQuery slider provided in www.jqueryui.com/slider/ looks like:

[image: jQuery Slider Bar UI]

Let's agree upon the fact that it looks ugly.

So, assume I made two PNG files in Photoshop, one for the bar and one for the handle.
Is there any way to redesign this gray, monotonous slider with my awesome images?

If you have another designable slider recommendation other than jQuery, that's also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [Link](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) to the API page

There is a paragraph which explains theming:

> ### Theming
>
> The slider widget uses the jQuery UI CSS framework to style its look
>   and feel. If slider specific styling is needed, the following CSS
>   class names can be used:
>
> `ui-slider:` The track of the slider control. This element will
>   additionally have a class name of `ui-slider-horizontal` or
>   `ui-slider-vertical` depending on the orientation of the slider.
>
> `ui-slider-handle:` The slider handles.
>
> `ui-slider-range:` The selected
>   range used when the range option is set. This element can additionally
>   have a class of `ui-slider-range-min` or `ui-slider-range-max` if the
>   range option is set to "min" or "max" respectively.

As you asked in comments an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jx4Zj/)

Comment: CSS styling may be of use, but I was looking for a way to use a specific "image" for my slider.

Comment: They use images as background, so You will be able to replace them. I've did this trick with couple of JqueryUI widgets.

Comment: Could you show me how that image replacement is done? Because this question has been driving me nuts for a while.

Comment: Added a Fiddle as you asked

Comment: Thank you very much, but one more thing: When the smiley is dragged, the edges of the image get highlighted in orange (using Chrome). How do you prevent that?